# .NET: WebClient() POST request error The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have a function which takes some time to execute. Then front-end application getting timeout issue. So, I'm planning to delegate pdf generate part and email send part as a separate post request.

But it gives exception : **The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.**

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateQuote([FromBody]CreateQuoteRequest model)
    {           
         // quote generate 
         if (quote.QuoteItems.Count<=15) {
            var strHtml = await LoadCustomPdf("QuotePDF", new { quote });                    
             _lfworkflowmessageService.SendQuoteEmail(strHtml,model.Email, quote);
         }
         else {
               string url = @"http://localhost:55390/api/client/SendQuoteTest";
               using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
               {
                    var data = new NameValueCollection();
                    data["quoteId"] = "1";
                    data["email"] = "email@email.com";

                    var response = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
                    string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
               }
          }          

     }    

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendQuoteTest([FromBody]string quoteId, [FromBody] string email)
    {
    return Ok();
    }
```